# Getting user details in other schema[mongoose]

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, mongoose

I'm getting my hands on mean stack development. I'm kinda stuck where my requirement is to get posted by functionality. I'm trying to build a simple classified ads app where a user adds/updates/deletes a classified. I'm able to do all of these but now I need to display the name of that particular user on that add who is logged in. I've researched online but couldn't get the solution.

My schema

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
    username: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    firstName: { type: String, required: true },
    lastName: { type: String, required: true },
    email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true, lowercase: true },
    phone: { type: Number, min: 10, unique: true },
    hash: String,
    salt: String
});

var ClassifiedSchema = new Schema({
    title: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    description: { type: String, required: true, },
    price: { type: Number, required: true },
    created: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    updated: { type: Date, default: null },
    contact: {
        name: String,
        phone: Number,
        email: String
    },
    image: String,
    user: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }
});
```

My route

```
router.route('/classifieds')
        .post(function(req, res) {
            var classified = new Classified(req.body);

            classified.save(function(err, classified) {
                if (err)
                    res.send(err);
                res.json(classified);
            });
        })
        .get(function(req, res) {
            Classified.find(function(err, classifieds) {
                if (err)
                    res.send(err);
                res.json(classifieds);
            });
        });

router.route('/register')
        .post(function(req, res) {
            if (!req.body.username || !req.body.password || !req.body.email || !req.body.firstName || !req.body.lastName) {
                return res.status(400).json({message: 'Please fill all the fields!'});
            };

            var user = new User(req.body);
            user.setPassword(req.body.password);

            user.save(function(err, user) {
                if (err)
                    res.send(err);
                res.json({ token: user.generateJWT()});
            });
        });

    router.route('/login')
        .post(function(req, res) {
            if (!req.body.username || !req.body.password) {
                return res.status(400).json({ message: 'Please fill all the fields!' });
            };

            passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info) {
                if (err)
                    res.send(err);
                if (user) {
                    return res.json({ token: user.generateJWT() });
                } else {
                    return res.status(401).json(info);
                };
            })(req, res);
        });
```

I want to know how do I get the username while posting the classified? I'm aware of the populate function but I've tried it and it doesn't seem to work.

**Update**

I've added my register and login route to show you the use of passport.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an authentication system like [passport](https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport) which sets req.user to current logged in user, then:

```
   .get(function(req, res) {
        Classified.find({user: req.user},function(err, classifieds) {
            if (err)
                res.send(err);
            res.json(classifieds);
        });
    });
```

Comment: Yes I'm using passport but I always get undefined whenever I try to access req.user

Comment: @fahad.kazi is the user logged in?

Comment: Yes I tried adding a classified when the user is logged in and tried printing req.user to the console. I got undefined.

Comment: I've added the the login route where I'm using passport to get token but I'm not sending user. Is that a problem?

Comment: Have you set the route as authentication required? And also are you sending token from the client side?

Comment: For now I'm not authenticating routes but yes I'm saving token in local storage on client side.

Comment: Authenticate the route and make sure that you are sending token in the request header.

Comment: Actually I tried to create this app by following up a tutorial and as I'm new to this I made a few mistakes. I skipped the authentication of routes and wasn't sending token to the header. Also the tutorial uses express-jwt so the user data is stored in payload. I'll have to research more on this. Please update your answer and I'll accept. Thanks for your help.